# Implementing breakpoints that resume safely in multithreaded code

Tags: c++, debugging, x86-64, breakpoints, machine-code

I'm writing a debugger and currently trying to make breakpoints work reliably when multiple threads hit them at the same time. As far as I know, most debuggers implement breakpoints by replacing the first byte of the instruction with 0xCC, and that's how I'm currently doing it as well. However, I don't see any way of restoring the original byte while still being able to stop other threads that are about to hit that breakpoint, without halting all running threads. Does anyone have any information on how that's usually achieved? Is halting all threads really the only solution?

Comment: As far as i know debuggers stops all threads.

Comment: There are usually a finite number of "hardware breakpoints" not subject to the same limitations, but not enough to use them for *all* breakpoints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With all threads stopped, you restore that byte, step *that one thread only* for one instruction, recreate the breakpoint, then resume execution of all threads.  If you are using one of the limited hardware debug registers, you can use RF to temporarily ignore the breakpoint for one instruction (see below).

Stopping just the one thread during debugging, while the other threads keep running, is just asking for trouble.  Consider how you'd handle hitting the same or a different breakpoint while you were stopped at the first?  Or if an exception occurs?

On the Intel CPUs, there is a flag that can be set in the EFLAGS register (the Resume Flag, bit 16).  When set this will allow executing the first instruction without triggering breakpoints, and will work when using the hardware breakpoints (and not the breakpoint instruction).

Chapter 17 in Volume 3 (the System Programming Guide, available for [download from Intel](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm)) contains lots of details on the Debug features of Intel IA-32 CPUs.

Comment: Well, that's exactly my question. I'm aware that temporarily pausing all threads is the common way to solve that. I'm asking if there's any way to avoid doing that.

Comment: @Kalinovcic - think that no another way. you suspend all thread before dbg_continue and set trace flag in thread context which hit breakpoint. after single step exception - you restore bp and resume another threads

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm - Thank you! I think your edit answered my question, I might know of a way of doing it now.

Comment: *or disable the hardware breakpoint* - for hardware breakpoint (set with `DRx`) we not need suspend another threads, because it per thread. suspend need only in case `int 3` memory patch

Comment: @RbMm I've reworded this some

Answer (score 2):

> I'm aware that temporarily pausing all threads is the common way to solve that. I'm asking if there's any way to avoid doing that.

The first thread to hit your `int3` software breakpoint is the one that you *want* to stop.

If other threads hit it before you can patch it back to the correct contents, resume those threads after removing the software breakpoint.  (**x86 has coherent instruction caches**, so you can safely modify a single code byte without other cores needing to run a fence / `isync` instruction to re-sync their instruction caches with data cache.  This is a harder problem on other ISAs.)

Other threads can see a small interruption.

---

Of course, if the user puts a breakpoint inside a critical section (with a lock held), or single-steps into a critical section, the other threads will block on that.  This is also possible for lockless code that isn't [lock-free (in the computer science sense)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm#Lock-freedom).

---

Examining and modifying memory while other threads are running is potentially risky.  Another thread could unmap memory just before you try to read or modify it.  As long as your debugger itself doesn't crash, it's up to the user how much of a mess they want to make, though.

Comment: really question very strong depend from os. say on windows - if exception occurs - system suspend all threads in process and then send notify to debugger from thread (on which was exception). and wait for debugger response (so cpu begin execute another software threads). here no any problems with instruction caches, where breakpoint (inside critical section or not - all another threads anyway will be suspended). debugger usually again suspend all another threads and set trace flag (0x100) in current thread. restore original byte and continue.

Comment: after single step exception - restore breakpoint and resume threads